# How to flatten a list with various data types (int, tuple)

Tags: python, list, tuples, flatten

Say I have a list with one or more tuples in it:

```
[0, 2, (1, 2), 5, 2, (3, 5)]
```

What's the best way to get rid of the tuples so that it's just an int list?

```
[0, 2, 1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 5]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flattening a shallow list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python)

Comment: Not really a dupe of that questions, since not every inner element is a tuple.

Comment: Then please consider my recursive solution below! :)

Comment: The answers below will work, but before you swap one of them in your code, ask yourself *why* you have a list like this in the first place.  Your code will be easier to understand if you could make the original list homogenous.

Comment: Yep, and consider that my generalized solution works for any datatype and any depth. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of solutions (using [itertools.chain](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> l = [0, 2, (1, 2), 5, 2, (3, 5)]
>>> list(chain(*(i if isinstance(i, tuple) else (i,) for i in l)))
[0, 2, 1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 5):

Using a nested list comprehension:

```
>>> lst = [0, 2, (1, 2), 5, 2, (3, 5)]
>>> [y for x in lst for y in (x if isinstance(x, tuple) else (x,))]
[0, 2, 1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def untuppleList(lst):
    def untuppleList2(x):
        if isinstance(x, tuple):
            return list(x)
        else:
            return [x]
    return [y for x in lst for y in untuppleList2(x)]
```

Then you can do `untuppleList([0, 2, (1, 2), 5, 2, (3, 5)])`.

Answer (score 1):

A more general recursive solution, that should apply to any iterable (except strings) and any depth of elements:

```
import collections

def flatten(iterable):
    results = []
    for i in iterable:
        if isinstance(i, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(i, basestring):
            results.extend(flatten(i))
        else:
            results.append(i)
    return results
```

And usage:

```
>>> flatten((1, 2, (3, 4), ('happy')))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'happy']
>>> flatten((1, 2, (3, 4, (5, 6)), ('happy'), {'foo': 'bar', 'baz': 123}))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'happy', 'foo', 'baz']
```

Comment: I'm going with ndpu's answer just by a hair because it's slightly more appropriate for my specific dataset, but I can see your solution being extremely useful as a general approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [flatten](http://funcy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/seqs.html#flatten) function from my [funcy](https://github.com/Suor/funcy) library:

```
from funcy import flatten
flat_list = flatten(your_list)
```

You can also peek at [its implementation](https://github.com/Suor/funcy/blob/1.0.0/funcy/seqs.py#L147).